# maximum size of collection of m-subset of n-set with fixed size of pairwise intersection

Tags: combinatorics

I'm wondering if there is any clearly solved partial results (if possible with document accessible via internet) for the problem of finding

the maximum size of collection of $m$-subsets of $n$-set with fixed size (say, $r$) for their pairwise intersection.

It is commented that this problem is open problem in this question 
[Number of subsets of size $k$ whose pairwise intersection is of given size j](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/506585/number-of-subsets-of-size-k-whose-pairwise-intersection-is-of-given-size-j)

I'm particularly interested in the case of $r=1$ or $m=3$ or both holding simultaneously.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your question sees related a bit (though clearly not the same) as http://mathoverflow.net/questions/163689/what-is-the-best-lower-bound-for-3-sunflowers

Answer (score 4):

A good starting point is the Ray-Chaudhuri–Wilson theorem, see for example [Alon–Babai–Suzuki](http://www.tau.ac.il/~nogaa/PDFS/suzuki1.pdf), who prove this theorem using the polynomial method. According to the theorem, the maximum size is always at most $n$, though this is not necessarily tight.

The case $m = 1$ is not too interesting — we must have $r = 0$, and then there is an obvious optimal bound of $n$ disjoint singletons.

When $r = 1$ there is a lower bound of $(n-1)/m$. This bound is tight for $n > m^2-m+1$, as shown by [Deza](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0095895674900598). When $n = m^2-m+1$ and $m+1$ is a prime power, there exist constructions with $n$ sets, given by finite projective planes. For example, when $m=3$ we get the Fano plane:
$$
\{1,2,3\}, \{1,4,5\}, \{1,6,7\}, \{2,4,6\}, \{2,5,7\}, \{3,4,7\}, \{3,5,6\}.
$$

Comment: Oops! $m=1$ was a typo. My particular interest resides in the case of $m=3$.

Comment: anyhow this gives me a glimpse of the picture. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know where one can find a proof of Deza's theorem in English? His original paper was French, and it's frustrating not to be able to find a proof.

Comment: Unfortunately I am unaware of any such account.