# Maximum number of subsets of a finite set intersecting in a given number of elements

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose that $X$ is a finite set of $N$ elements. Fix $b,n$ and consider sets $S_j\subset X$ with cardinality $n$ and with $S_j\cap S_k$, $j\neq k$, always of cardinality $b$. Let $B$ the maximum number of subsets we can find.
According to the Ray-Chaudhuri–Wilson theorem (see [maximum size of collection of m-subset of n-set with fixed size of pairwise intersection](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1161167/maximum-size-of-collection-of-m-subset-of-n-set-with-fixed-size-of-pairwise-inte)), we have $B\leq N$.

I would like to know for which values of $b,n$ we have equality $B=N$.
I have found the following values:

- for $n=b+1$, it is $N=b+2$.
- for $b=1$ and $n=p^a+1$ ($p$ prime), we have $N=n^2-n+1$.
- for $b=2$ and $n=4$, it is $N=8$.

(Sorry if this should be posted in other place. Please feel free to relocate it if necessary)